# Gridview DataSource doesn't update

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, dataset, sqlcommand

With a button press I'm trying to update the GridView on my ASP.net site with Database from SQL server with other table but it doesnt change, there is no "catch".

The GridView doesn't appear.

```
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1;
        sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ELAD_HA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Users;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand sqlCommand1;
        sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TBUsers ORDER BY Name", sqlConnection1);
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand1);
            SqlCommandBuilder comb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adptr);
            adptr.Fill(ds,"T1");

            GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["T1"];

            //GridView2.DataSource = ds;
            //GridView2.DataMember = "T1";
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            SuccessLabel1.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with the code?
P.S
can I changed the DataSource to a GridView that I chose a Data Source from its menu ? (from the "split" screen).

Thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling databind to update the content:

```
GridView2.DataBind();
```

Best regards

Comment: Thanks, can I changed the DataSource to a GridView that I chose a Data Source from its menu ?  (from the "split" screen).